# how to set path for apache/ tomcat?

Tags: apache, tomcat, path

The default is www/webroot. Where may I set the path so that my localhost points somewhere else?

Comment: That isn't recognize as "default path" of Apache Tomcat. Aren't you confusing with Apache HTTP Server? Maybe you've both Apache HTTP Server and Apache Tomcat running for some reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the server.xml in your tomcat config directory. There is a property "appBase".